# Changing cell format in ag-grid/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, grid, ag-grid

I am displaying numbers in my cells and for the colDefs, I only want to show them to 2dp. So within my colDefs I have this -

```
valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) => params.value?.price?.toFixed(2)
```

I would like to add the ability for the user to double click on the cell and for it to show the full number (but when they click away it goes back to the 2dp format).

I have attached onCellDoubleClicked to my grid however I am having trouble sorting this.

```
    <Grid
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      {...gridOptions}
      quickFilterText={searchValue}
      onCellDoubleClicked={manageCellDoubleClick}
    />
```

I know there is setDataValue available in the click event as I tried to use this however I don't want to change the data (because I still want the full number to be always there on copy/paste/export etc.). I just want the full number to be revealed and then for it to go back to the 2dp format when you click away.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `onCellDoubleClicked` event to trigger a toggle on variable `isFull` on the row data.

```
const cellDoubleClicked = (params) => {
  console.log(1)
  const data = params.data;
  data['showFull'] = !data['showFull'];
  params.node.setData(data);
}
```

On the formatter, using a ternary condition we can toggle the full/rounded value as shown below!

```
const customFormatter = (params) => params.data.showFull ? params.value : params && params.value && params.value.toFixed(2);
```

Then finally, we can add a `onCellClicked` listener to reset the `isFull` property to false, to bring it back to the old state, it only works when you click another cell in the grid!

```
  const onCellClicked = useCallback((event) => {
    console.log(event);
    setRowData(rowData.map(x => {
      x.showFull = false;
      return x;
    }));
  }, []);
```

full code

```
'use strict';

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import React, { StrictMode, useMemo, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import './styles.css';


const customFormatter = (params) => params.data.showFull ? params.value : params && params.value && params.value.toFixed(2);

const cellDoubleClicked = (params) => {
  console.log(1)
  const data = params.data;
  data['showFull'] = !data['showFull'];
  params.node.setData(data);
}


const createRowData = () => {
  var rowData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    rowData.push({
      price: Math.random() * 100,
    });
  }
  return rowData;
};

const GridExample = () => {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: '100%', height: '100%' }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }), []);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(createRowData());
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', valueFormatter: customFormatter, onCellDoubleClicked: cellDoubleClicked },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      cellClass: 'number-cell',
    };
  }, []);


  const onCellClicked = useCallback((event) => {
    console.log(event);
    setRowData(rowData.map(x => {
      x.showFull = false;
      return x;
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div
        style={gridStyle}
        className={
          "ag-theme-quartz"
        }
      >
        <AgGridReact
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <GridExample />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BjnYxrybkfe8S6Vi?open=index.jsx)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this would only apply it to a single cell right?

Comment: @complexpie yes

Comment: For the onCellClicked function, what exactly are we doing there? Im not currently setting rowData anywhere. I set gridData in the parent file and also set columnDefs. Is it still okay to do this? What do I need to pass to this?

Comment: Do I need to add a showFull key to my data?

Comment: @complexpie Yes, if needed sure, keep it an optional parameter, since its not much use!

Answer (score 0):

possible disadvantage of this is that you then mutate rowData with view logic which IMHO is not ideal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).